# Erasing is not working

Tags: ios-simulator, ios5

I draw the lines and any shapes as i want but while erasing it not working,

For drawing i used the following code

in this code i drawn by using quartz core

```
previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
                previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
                currentPoint = [touch locationInView:m_img];


                //
                previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
                previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
                currentPoint = [touch locationInView:m_img];
                // calculate mid point
                CGPoint mid1 = [self midPoint:previousPoint1 :previousPoint2];
                CGPoint mid2 =[self midPoint:currentPoint :previousPoint1];
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(m_img.frame.size);
                [m_img.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, m_img.frame.size.width, m_img.frame.size.height)];
                CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
                // Use QuadCurve is the key
                CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
                CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace(context);   



                //CGContextSetStrokeColor(<#CGContextRef context#>, <#const CGFloat *components#>)
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
                CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context,m_width);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);
                m_img.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and for erasing the drawing i used the following code

```
            m_widthString=[userdefault valueForKey:@"EraserWidth"];  
            m_width=[m_widthString floatValue];
            previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
            previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
            currentPoint = [touch locationInView:m_img];
            previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
            previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:m_img];
            currentPoint = [touch locationInView:m_img];
            // calculate mid point
            CGPoint mid1 = [self midPoint:previousPoint1 :previousPoint2]; 
            CGPoint mid2 =[self midPoint:currentPoint :previousPoint1];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(m_img.frame.size);
            [m_img.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, m_img.frame.size.width, m_img.frame.size.height)];

            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context,m_width);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
            CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
            CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
            m_img.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

while erasing i changed blend mode clear even if it is not working

but is not working please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for erasing u have to take trasferent image view 
and use  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
 its working right now for me...